# path to the project director in django

Tags: python, django

This is my project tree:

```
projectname
    projectname
        init.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    appname
        init.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        test.py
        views.py
        urls.py
    templates
        base.html
        login.html
```

Now in the settings.py I am using this code:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "projectname", "templates"),
    )

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "projectname", "static", "static-only")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "projectname", "static", "media")
```

How can I get the path of the project directory, so that I don't need to type the project name `projectname` in the code and  use that code in any other django project?

**Update**

Or can I just use this

```
BASE_DIR+'/templates'
BASE_DIR+'/static/media'
```

Or is it a bad idea?

Comment: You could just put those lines in a directories.py file and import that logic to settings.py, then you can reuse settings.py and just change directories.py for a different django project.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I could? But that's more work. :D  Or, can I just use this for the path as `BASE_DIR+'/templates'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BASE_DIR *already* includes "projectname". When you do `os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)`, you go *up* a level from projectname; only to add it back in. Don't do that.

Instead, just use BASE_DIR directly:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [`os.path.abspath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath):

```
# Project root is intended to be used when building paths,
# e.g. ``os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'relative/path')``.
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))

# Absolute path to the directory where ``collectstatic``
# will collect static files for deployment.
#
# For more information on ``STATIC_ROOT``, visit
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#static-root
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/')

# Absolute path to the directory that will hold uploaded files.
#
# For more information on ``MEDIA_ROOT``, visit
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#media-root
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'uploads/')
```